# How to express many measurements of distance, height, etc

Tags: sentence-construction

> *C.brachyotis* roosted in the spots with **distance** x ± 0.y m, **height** x.x ± y.y m, **temperature** x ± y.yoC, **humidity** xx.y ± x.xy%, **light intensity** xx.y ± xy lux, **sound intensity** yy.x ± xxy db, **wind speed** y ± x m/s, **oxygen percentage level** x ± y %, **ammonia compound** xy ± y ppm.

Is this sentence easily readable by audience?

Comment: Are you asking about each of the bold+number+error-bar+unit sets, or about the sentence as a whole? And have you considered reformulating this as a table?

Comment: @NathanTuggy The sentence as a whole. There is surely a table form of it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Is preposition "with" as a connector between "the spots" and "distance" appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Each of the individual measurements is fairly readable, and it's not ungrammatical (except for lacking the conjunction "and" before the last entry). But taken all together the sentence is quite unwieldy, and the formatting doesn't do enough to break up the repetition. It's also not entirely clear from this quote whether the various measurements are supposed to be joined inclusively or exclusively — that is, whether 95% (or whatever chosen confidence interval) of roosting spots were within every one of these measurements simultaneously, or whether 95% were within a given distance, 95% (possibly a different 95%) within a given height, and so forth.

To break up the sentence more effectively, use a table, or split it into multiple sentences or paragraphs, grouping by related measurements (distance and height; temperature and humidity; light, sound, and wind; and chemical concentrations).

To clearly explain that the measurements are inclusive, say something like "*C. brachyotis* roosting spots fell within **all** of the following ranges [with p<0.05]:" and then go on to give the measurements. Or to instead explain that they're exclusive, try "**Each** of the following ranges **individually** characterizes *C. brachyotis* roosting spots [with p<0.05]". The bolded words in each case are the important ones to make this clear.

Comment: Your answer helps a lot.